# How to improve method of opening file in python then writing to another?

Tags: python

Very simple I want to edit a virtual host files and replace the tags I made with some actual data:

```
import os, re
with open('virt_host', 'r+') as virtual
    file = virtual.read()
    file = re.sub('{{dir}}', '/home/richard', file)
    file = re.sub('{{user}}', 'richard', file)
    file = re.sub('{{domain_name}}', 'richard.com', file)

with open('new_virt', 'w+') as new_file
    new_file.write(file)
    new_file.close()
```

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 3):

```
import os, re
```

Here, make sure you put a colon after `virtual`

```
with open('virt_host', 'r+') as virtual:
```

Avoid using built-in Python keywords as variables (such as `file` here)

```
    f = virtual.read()
```

This part is explicit, which is a good thing. Depending on whether or not you have control over how your variables are defined, you could use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to pass a dictionary containing your values into the read file, which would save a few function calls.

```
    f = re.sub('{{dir}}', '/home/richard', f)
    f = re.sub('{{user}}', 'richard', f)
    f = re.sub('{{domain_name}}', 'richard.com', f)
```

Same as above regarding the colon

```
with open('new_virt', 'w+') as new_file:
    new_file.write(f)
```

One of the main benefits of using a context manager (such as `with`) is that it handles things such as closing by itself. Therefore, you can remove the `new_file.close()` line.

Here is the full code with the adjustments noted. Hope it helps!

```
import os, re

with open('virt_host', 'r+') as virtual:
    f = virtual.read()
    f = re.sub('{{dir}}', '/home/richard', f)
    f = re.sub('{{user}}', 'richard', f)
    f = re.sub('{{domain_name}}', 'richard.com', f)

with open('new_virt', 'w+') as new_file:
    new_file.write(f)
```

Comment: @Jason No prob man!